# Create theme files for plugin

Tags: plugins, themes

Basically I've made a plugin to create a new post type (event).

Now I want to create a `single-event.php` layout file.

I don't want to have to stick it in the theme folder, I want to put it into my plugin folder. How do I make wordpress know its there?

Thanks

Comment: well dice the template system looks in the themes folder I think that this is the only way unless there is a filter. usually you put the register post type in the functions.pho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code that will let you return your single-event.php if the post type is event:

```
function my_event_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'event') {
        return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-event.php';
    return $single_template;
}

add_filter( "single_template", "my_event_template" ) ;
```

Comment: I learned something today. Yay. thanks hameedullah i was not sure if there was a filter or not for this.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you learn something new. :)